# Unmatched Query with Limits

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database that uses a unique ID for each transaction. The transaction ID is the last two digits of a year followed by a four digit sequential number (eg. 0100 to 9999). That number resets back to 0100 at the start of each year. Not all numbers are used each year. Example, the last transaction in 2012 was 12-0409, in 2011 it was 11-0500. These numbers are not currently generated in the database but are created manually. I am in the process of getting them to switch to using automation but in the meantime I have to create patches to fix errors.

In the database, I have one table and one query. The query ([Offer Check]) lists the Transaction ID ([HL#]) and shows just the last four in two formats, one as a number format ([NumList]) and one as a text format ([TextList]). The table is a basic table that lists all the numbers between 0100 and 9999. I am trying to create a query that allows me to identify which Transaction IDs are missing, i.e. I have 13-0250 and 13-0252 but not 13-0251. I can create the query that identifies which numbers are missing, however it also lists all the numbers past the latest Transaction ID. How can I limit the query to the current maximum transaction ID #?

This is what I have so far.

```sql
SELECT YearlyOfferIds.YOID
FROM
    YearlyOfferIds
    LEFT JOIN [Offer Check]
    ON YearlyOfferIds.[YOID] = [Offer Check].[TextList]
WHERE ((([Offer Check].TextList) Is Null));
```

And I'm trying to add or something that does the same thing.

```sql
SELECT Max([Offer Check].NumList) AS MaxOfNumList
FROM [Offer Check];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query, `SELECT Max(...`, can be translated into a `DMax` expression.

```sql
DMax("NumList", "Offer Check")
```

My hunch is you can use that `DMax` in your first query's `WHERE` clause to limit the rows returned from `YearlyOfferIds`.  Unfortunately, I don't know the name of the `YearlyOfferIds` field which you want to compare with the maximum `[Offer Check].NumList`.  So I'll just call that field *some_field*.

```sql
WHERE
        YearlyOfferIds.some_field <= DMax("NumList", "Offer Check")
    AND [Offer Check].TextList Is Null
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That didn't quite work out but that is because of my data. It got me to a spot where I could use my limited knowledge to get the job done. Just so you know, there was only one field in the YearlyOfferIds table. It is called YOID.